# "occur in/to genes"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, difference

During my research,  I came cross some context found in articles.

> 1. These changes occur **in** genes that are essential for development.
> 2. Sometimes changes occur **to** genes, resulting in medical conditions.

When should I use "in", and when should I use "to"?

Comment: Please tell us what research you have done to solve your problem. Have you tried a dictionary? What did you find? Have you tried looking up similar phrases in google? What did you find? Have you tried google books or google news? Also, tell us which you think is correct, and why. Without "research effort" this question is likely to get closed. See [Please, everyone … details. Please!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: Actually I did some research using google  to get some context and what I found was that both of the prepositions were right to use but that was my conclusion and that is why I want to see If anyone has a different opinion.

Comment: That is fine. You should edit your question and put this comment in there. And then delete the comment. The point is to give us some indication of where to begin, we should know what you have done. If you found similar sentence that uses both prepositions, then quote those sentences and put them in your question.

Comment: Did you look up "mutation" in dictionaries for example sentences? I looked it up in Cambridge dictionary and found this: *"the change that **happens in** an organism’s genes which produces differences that are passed to new organisms by reproduction, or the process of this change"*

Comment: Yes actually I did ,but my point is why you can find some people  use "in" while the others use "to" . Is it because a difference in the context or just they are used interchangably.                              Note : I made some modifications to the question.

Comment: My work here was to point out how you can improve your question. Yes, you have made the proper corrections. That's great! Continue to follow this structure (research, findings, examples, and then clearly stating the question) in all your questions. That will get you great answers!